# how triangle inequality works here?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

In a Canadian Math Olympiad Problem's solution, They used triangle inequality . The problem is as follows. the problem is the fourth problem from the 2019 Canada national olympiad.

Let $n$ be an integer greater than 1.Let $a_0,a_1,a_2,...a_n$ be real numbers with $a_1=a_{n-1}$=0
prove that for any real number k,
\begin{align*}|a_0|-|a_n|\le\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}|a_i+ka_{i+1}+a_{i+2}|\end{align*}
here is the official solution https://www2.cms.math.ca/Competitions/CMO/archive/sol2019.pdf
How triangle inequality is used here in algebra.Can anyone tell me how triangle inequality is used in algebra?

Answer (score 1):

From
$$0 = -a_0 z^2 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2})z^{i+2} + a_n z^n  \text{,}$$
we have
\begin{align*}
a_0 z^2 &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2})z^{i+2} + a_n z^n  \\
|a_0 z^2| &= \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2})z^{i+2} + a_n z^n \right|  \\
\end{align*}
The left-hand side is $|a_0| \, |z|^2$.  Applying the triangle inequality to the right hand side twice, we obtain \begin{align*}
&\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2})z^{i+2} + a_n z^n \right|  \\
&\qquad\leq \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2})z^{i+2}\right| + \left|a_n z^n \right|  \\
&\qquad = \left|a_n z^n \right| + \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2})z^{i+2}\right|  \\
&\qquad \leq \left|a_n z^n \right| + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\left|( a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2})z^{i+2} \right|  \\
&\qquad = |a_n| \, |z|^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\left|a_i - k a_{i+1} - a_{i+2} \right| |z|^{i+2}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

With the equation
$$a_0z^2=a_nz^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i-ka_{i+1}-a_{i+2})z^{i+2}$$
using the triangle inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
|a_0z^2|&=\left|a_nz^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i-ka_{i+1}-a_{i+2})z^{i+2}\right|\\
&\leq |a_nz^n|+\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i-ka_{i+1}-a_{i+2})z^{i+2}\right|
\end{align*}
and using again $n-1$ times with $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(a_i-ka_{i+1}-a_{i+2})z^{i+2}$ you get the inequality showed